# Invalid column names, using a complex type

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm getting the following error:

> SqlException (0x80131904):
>
> Invalid column name 'FirstName'.
>
> Invalid column name 'LastName'.
>
> Invalid column name 'FirstName'.
>
> Invalid column name 'LastName'.
>
> Invalid column name 'FirstName'.
>
> Invalid column name 'LastName'.

Firstly I'm a bit confused as to why I get three errors for each column.
The code where the first and last names is in a complex type:

```
    [ComplexType]
    public class FullName : ValueObject<FullName> {

    public FullName(string firstName, string lastName) {
        FirstName = firstName;
        LastName = lastName;
    }

    public FullName(FullName fullName)
        : this(fullName.FirstName, fullName.LastName) {
    }

    internal FullName() {
    }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(25, ErrorMessage="A maximum of 25 characters is allowed.")]
    [Column("FirstName")]
    public string FirstName { get; private set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(25, ErrorMessage = "A maximum of 25 characters is allowed.")]
    [Column("LastName")]
    public string LastName { get; private set; }

    public string AsFormattedName() {
        return this.FirstName + " " + this.LastName;
    }

    public FullName WithChangedFirstName(string firstName) {
        return new FullName(firstName, this.LastName);
    }

    public FullName WithChangedLastName(string lastName) {
        return new FullName(this.FirstName, lastName);
    }
    public override string ToString() {
        return "FullName [firstName=" + FirstName + ", lastName=" + LastName + "]";
    }
}
```

The ValueObject class is from a Jimmy Bogard blog:
http://grabbagoft.blogspot.co.uk/2007/06/generic-value-object-equality.html

This is being used in an ApplicationUser class which extends IdentityUser from Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.

```
public partial class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser {

    [Required]
    public FullName Fullname { get; private set; }
}
```

Thanks!

Eric.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got it working. I'm not *exactly* sure what the solution was, but I had an database existing database with the same name, but different case. I deleted this, and changed the line in Global.asax from

Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges());

to

Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways());

Answer (score 0):

If you are retrieving data, the setters for the FirstName and LastName properties cannot be private. Try changing the properties to:

```
public string FirstName { get; set; }
public string LastName { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thanks Dave. The reason for having private setters is to try and follow Domain Driven Design principles as much as I can.